# Link LSOA codes with ordnance survey postcodes and endpoint

Tags: sparql, rdf, linked-data

I am new to linked data and trying to link ordnance survey postcodes to LSOA data.

I am using the OS linked Data Sparql API and the end point is:

```
http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/apis/sparql
```

I have a query which returns the postcodes, although I am trying to link LSOA codes with the postcodes to learn from. The code I have so far is:

```
SELECT ?postcode WHERE { 

        ?postcodeUnit a <http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/postcode/PostcodeUnit>
        BIND (STRAFTER((STR(?postcodeUnit)),'postcodeunit/') as ?postcode)  

}limit 10
```

This code brings back the postcodes, but I am trying to link to LSOA codes.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be a bit stuck with this data source.

http://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/ontology/postcode/PostcodeUnit

Shows that there is no LSOA data associated with a postcode unit. And a quick look at the RDF for the site shows that they don't have a field called LSOA.

Comment: ok, thanks for the quick reply, do you have any suggestions please? I was using the opendatacommunities but there is a bug with the end point @jeremy